# Jira resources fail with net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Tags: http, jira, iptables

I am running Jira Server on a virtual CentOS machine on port `8081`. Using `iptables` I reroute port `80` connections to `8081`. When accessing the server over port `8081` everything works fine, but over `80` the resources don't load, only the HTML. What's going on?

[image: Jira Page]

In the console I get the following kind of errors:

[image: Resource errors]
[image: Resource errors #2]

My redirects:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i lo -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081

# iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -p tcp --dport 8081 -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i ens192 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8081

# iptables -t nat -L --line-numbers
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8081
2    REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http 
redir ports 8081

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

My `server.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<Server port="8006" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <Service name="Catalina">
        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         DEFAULT - Direct connector with no proxy for unproxied access to Jira.

         If using a http/https proxy, comment out this connector.
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->

        <!-- Relaxing chars because of JRASERVER-67974 -->
        <Connector port="8081" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false"/>

        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         HTTP - Proxying Jira via Apache or Nginx over HTTP

         If you're proxying traffic to Jira over HTTP, uncomment the below connector and comment out the others.
         Ensure the proxyName and proxyPort are updated with the appropriate information if necessary as per the docs.

         See the following for more information:

            Apache - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/4xQLM
            nginx  - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/DAFmGQ
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->

        <!--
        <Connector port="8080" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false" scheme="http"
                   proxyName="<subdomain>.<domain>.com" proxyPort="80"/>

        -->
        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         HTTPS - Proxying Jira via Apache or Nginx over HTTPS

         If you're proxying traffic to Jira over HTTPS, uncomment the below connector and comment out the others.
         Ensure the proxyName and proxyPort are updated with the appropriate information if necessary as per the docs.

         See the following for more information:

            Apache - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/PTT3MQ
            nginx  - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/DAFmGQ
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->

        <!--
        <Connector port="8080" relaxedPathChars="[]|" relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" connectionTimeout="20000" enableLookups="false"
                   maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="HTTP/1.1" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" redirectPort="8443"
                   acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" bindOnInit="false" secure="true" scheme="https"
                   proxyName="<subdomain>.<domain>.com" proxyPort="443"/>
        -->

        <!--
         ==============================================================================================================
         AJP - Proxying Jira via Apache over HTTP or HTTPS

         If you're proxying traffic to Jira using the AJP protocol, uncomment the following connector line
         See the following for more information:

            Apache - https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/QiJ9MQ
         ==============================================================================================================
        -->

        <!--
        <Connector port="8009" URIEncoding="UTF-8" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3"/>
        -->

        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

                <Context path="" docBase="${catalina.home}/atlassian-jira" reloadable="false" useHttpOnly="true">
                    <Resource name="UserTransaction" auth="Container" type="javax.transaction.UserTransaction"
                              factory="org.objectweb.jotm.UserTransactionFactory" jotm.timeout="60"/>
                    <Manager pathname=""/>
                    <JarScanner scanManifest="false"/>
                </Context>

            </Host>
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
                   pattern="%a %{jira.request.id}r %{jira.request.username}r %t &quot;%m %U%q %H&quot; %s %b %D &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot; &quot;%{jira.request.assession.id}r&quot;"/>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: If you're using iptables to redirect port 80 to port 8081 on the same machine anyway, why not just set up Jira's Connector to respond on port 80?

Comment: @ScottDudley because doing so requires root permissions for Jira AFAIK